# Logstash: Attaching to previous line using multiline attaches somewhere else

Tags: filter, multiline, logstash, kibana

I have a filter that looks like so:

```
    multiline {
        pattern => "(^.+Exception.*)|(^\tat .+)"
        negate => false
        what => "previous"
    }
```

But for some reason, it's not attaching to the previous line for lines with ^\tat. Sometimes it does, but most of the time it doesn't. It attaches to the line way far back. I don't see anything wrong with my code.

Does anyone know if this is a bug?

Edit: This worked properly just now but couple minutes after it doesn't work again. Is it a buffer overflow? How would I debug this?

Edit: Example of success:

```
2014-06-20 09:09:07,989 http-bio-8080-exec-629 WARN com.rubiconproject.rfm.adserver.filter.impl.PriorityFilter - Request : NBA_DIV=Zedge_Tier1_App_MPBTAG_320x50_ROS_Android&NBA_APPID=4E51A330AD7A0131112022000A93D4E6&NBA_PUBID=111657&NBA_LOCATION_LAT=&NBA_LOCATION_LNG=&NBA_KV=device_id_sha-1_key=5040e46d15bd2f37b3ba58860cc94c1308c0ca4b&_v=2_0_0&id=84472439740784460, Response : Unable to Score Ads.. Selecting first one and Continuing...
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 8, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
```

Edit: Example of failure:

```
2014-06-20 09:02:31,139 http-bio-8080-exec-579 WARN  com.rubiconproject.rfm.adserver.web.AdRequestController - Request : car=vodafone UK&con=0&model=iPhone&bdl=com.racingpost.general&sup=adm,dfp,iAd&id=8226846&mak=Apple&sze=320x50&TYP=1&rtyp=json&app=F99D88D0FDEC01300BF5123139244773&clt=MBS_iOS_SDK_2.4.0&dpr=2.000000&apver=10.4&osver=7.1&udid=115FC62F-D4FF-44E0-8D92-5A060043EFDD&pub=111407&tud=3&osn=iPhone OS&, Response : No Ad Selected to Serve..Exiting
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
```

My file has 13000+ lines, and when it errors, it attaches to couple hundred lines back. But strangely each attaches to a line with the exact same offset in between (by offset I mean those couple hundred lines that it skips).

Comment: Can you provide your logs example?

Comment: The example of a success and fail are in my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logs is java stack logs.
You can try to use this pattern. Use the date as the pattern, which is the beginning of each log.

```
input {
    stdin{}
}

filter {
   multiline {
     pattern => "^(?>\d\d){1,2}-(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[12][0-9])|(?:3[01])|[1-9])"
     what => "previous"
   }
}

output {
    stdout {
            codec => "rubydebug"
    }
}
```

This pattern parses the date, if the line do not start with date, logstash will multiline it. 
I have try it with your logs, it's worked on both two logs.

Hope this  can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that doesn't quite solve my problem as that is already basically what I'm doing.

Comment: I'll try this next time the bug pops up again. But, I don't know why my multiline filter would still jump couple hundred lines to be attached.